# jquery animate doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

When I use jQuery `.animate()` with a bootstrap progress bar to set progress percentages, it only works normal the first time I use it.
I've made a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/43bqP/

When it just had to go to 50, it somehow first goes above 500 and then animates back to 50.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about to calculate it into pixels? Snippet of code:

```
...
var stepBy  = $("div.progress").width() / steps.length;
...
$("div#update div.progress div.progress-bar").animate({
   width   : (stepBy + (stepBy * step))
}
...
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DYVL9/) with full code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to

```
duration : pauseBetweenSteps / 2
```

and the `alert()` method called when all the steps have been executed, but the animation is still in act.

I'm not sure to understand why you're setting `duration` like this. Try leaving the default (400) by unsetting it, and add a `setTimeout` by 500ms around the `alert("done")`, to be sure the animation has ended.

Working eg. http://jsfiddle.net/eEE87/